# POST method is not set

Tags: android

During debug, I realize that all the request property and method I set is not executed at all. Can anyone explain why?

Because of this, whenever I request an output from `URLConnection`, that line will create a runtime error.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        url = new URL("https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/80b0369fe0df48308d956e2ddce52806/services/6379155db28f4c91b84e78d268a927f9/execute?api-version=2.0&format=swagger");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        urlConnection = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
       // urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        String api_key = "Bearer api_key";
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", api_key);
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
         } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   try {
        urlConnection.connect();
        urlConnection.getContent();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are doing network operations on UI thread which android OS does not allow so, you should put your code in an async task

like so :

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            URL url = null;
            URLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/80b0369fe0df48308d956e2ddce52806/services/6379155db28f4c91b84e78d268a927f9/execute?api-version=2.0&format=swagger");
                urlConnection = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                // urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                String api_key = "Bearer api_key";
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", api_key);
                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                urlConnection.connect();
                urlConnection.getContent();
            }
            catch (IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    task.execute();
```

also make sure you have intenet permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

also your api key "Bearer api_key" is not a valid api key

Comment: Thx for your comment. I tried , and the line URL.connect() worked, but not the next one getContent (). It will jump to IOexception in the catch block. When I check the variables , again it showed URLconnection 's method is GET, and none of the request property is there.   The only difference is that it sent something to internet, but no reaction.  Is it possible that my URL got some error.? I tried to split it into 3 parts , but it remains the same.

Comment: what is the message of the exception that was thrown, also please check your API key.

Comment: At the get content line, Java.io. file not found exception :https:https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/80b0369fe0df48308d956e2ddce52806/services/6379155db28f4c91b84e78d268a927f9/execute?api-version=2.0&format=swagger is catched in Io exception block.

Comment: And also in get response code, I got number 400.   API keys is copied from the backed servicer, so it's not a problem. At last , I got the same Io exception in the input stream.

Answer (score 1):

1. sending a network request in `Activity.onCreate` will crash your app with a [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html), you should never do that
2. I strongly suggest using other networking libraries which will take care of most of the things you're struggling with here such as [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp), [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit)

Answer (score 0):

try the following the send post request

```
try {
    url = new URL("https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/80b0369fe0df48308d956e2ddce52806/services/6379155db28f4c91b84e78d268a927f9/execute");

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    String requestBody = "api-version=2.0&format=swagger"
    urlConnection = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();
    String api_key = "Bearer api_key";

    urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", api_key);
    urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8");
    writer.write(requestBody);
    writer.flush();
    if (urlconnection.getResponseCode() == 200) 
     {                  
            InputStream input = urlconnection.getInputStream();
            //parse the response
     }

  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```